# retrieve cookie data in codeigniter after printing it

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies, session-cookies

Here is my folder structure, in **codeigniter**

```
- application
      - folder 1
      - folder 2
      - folder 3
```

in **folder 1**, i am going to login, that time i have set the session. Now that session i want to access to use it on **folder 2**. i tried with cookies but i am getting data like this:

```
a:15:
{
s:10:"session_id";s:32:"2900d1198a8ebee54202e02087b54ef0";
s:10:"ip_address";s:15:"1.1.10.0";
s:10:"user_agent";
s:72:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0";
s:13:"last_activity";i:1450264226;s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";
s:5:"LOGIN";b:1;
s:6:"email";s:21:"test@gmail.com";
s:5:"name";s:13:"test user";
s:9:"logintype";s:14:"ad";
}
990e6c416c4fe422091dd83ab6a9b6b6b5f36e3d
```

Now how can i get **name** from that cookie data?

want to print **name** in **folder 2's** view.

I have **2 folder's 1) folder 1 and 2) folder2.** 
I want to allow login from folder 1 as well from folder 2.. so if i have logged-in from first folder then when i try to access using folder 2 then it should display name because it is already logged-in.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it:

```
<?php
$cisess_cookie = $_COOKIE['ci_session'];
$cisess_cookie = stripslashes($cisess_cookie);
$cisess_cookie = unserialize($cisess_cookie);
$name = $cisess_cookie['name'];
echo $name;
?>
```

it will print the name.